# Video in cordova app on ios without sound

Tags: android, ios, video, cordova, cordova-3

I am building an app for both iOS and Android with Cordova 3.1. On iOS, the videos will be played as they should, but always without sound. And I don't know why.

I have intergrated the videos with the html-tag like this:

```
<video class="video" controls="true">
   <source src="http://www.domain.de/Video1/video.mp4">
   <source src="http://www.domain.de/Video1/video.ogv">
</video>
```

The following cordova plugins are installed:

```
$ cordova plugin list
 [ 'org.apache.cordova.device',
   'org.apache.cordova.file',
   'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser',
   'org.apache.cordova.media' ]
```

And the config.xml on iOS looks like this:

```
....
<feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="true" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
</feature>
```

I have also tried name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" and name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false".

On the iOS Simulator (of Xcode) everything is all right. But on my iOS-device (iOS 7), the videos will be played always without sound. The same with audio-files. I hear nothing.
On Android it works.

What is going wrong?

Comment: **Update**: If I use headphones at my iOS-device, I hear the sound of the video.

Comment: Okay, I have the solution . . .

Comment: What was the solution @user3543071 ? I am having the same issue!

Comment: You can even post the answer to your own question, and others will upvote it as it is referenced! (That's the whole point of the system. ;)

Answer (score 16):

Solution (for me): Turn your phone off silent.

I'm not kidding. Try it.

Comment: As a non-iOS user, this got me too. Even after reading this answer though, it took me awhile to figure out that the little toggle switch above the volume buttons is the ringer muter. Unlike with native apps, HTML5 video is subject to this switch's position.

Comment: Some apps play audio even with silent mode on. How would you achieve that on a cordova app?

Comment: thanks for the answer, it was so silly to find that my iPhone was on silent, and I had been debugging my cordova app for two days due to no audio in live video play.